# Independent and joint probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

I got this question from my statistics teacher, but his answer made me confused. The question is this..

Given that A, B and C are three independent events such that P (A)=0.2 ,P(B)=0.6 ,P (C)=0.5, then the joint probability for the three events is:

a) 0.751
b) 0.06
c) 0.500
d) 0

My teacher said that "d" is the correct answer. However I believe that "b" is more reasonable answer, because the events are independent and also joint (not mutually exclusive). So what do you think?

Comment: independent leads to the product $0.06$, which mutually exclusive is not possible when the sum is greater than $1$

Comment: Who is a statistics doctor?

Comment: The statistics doctor is the one who holds the cure for OP's teacher.

Comment: You don't need to say "joint" to assure "not mutually exclusive".  If two events, P and Q, ARE mutually exclusive then the probability of "P given Q" or "Q given P" is 0 so they are not "independent".  Any independent events are automatically "not mutually exclusive".

Answer (score 1):

b) is correct. By definition, the probability of the intersection of independent events is the product of the individual probabilities. Your teacher is wrong, or perhaps you misunderstood each other.